# Trust anchor for certification path not found. - React native app with expo, calling a .net core api

Tags: android, react-native, .net-core, expo, webapi

i'm new to android development,

I have a `react native` application running with `expo`.

I run the app on an android emulator.

I also have a `.net core webapi` running in localhost.

I get this error with the axios call to the backend:

`Java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`

I know that .net core is adding a self-signed certificate that I can manually add in android app manifest file to accept it.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

But in expo app, we have access to a app.json file instead of the manifest so we cannot proceed this way.
https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/

This is my `\res\xml\network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

With my self-signed localhost certificat at location `\res\xml\raw`

I dont know if i'm looking at the right place, but is their a way to prevent this error with the app.json file ?

Or any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a localhost secure tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/product/secure-tunnels)

This forward to a secure tunnel

```
Forwarding     https://[randomAddress].ngrok.io -> https://localhost:5555/
```

Then I change Axios base url

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://[randomAddress].ngrok.io',
});
```

Since it's a free acount, the `[randomAddress]` might change at each restart, so I need to update `baseURL`